# Get "this" reference for custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I'm trying to convert a JS working code to a jQuery code but I failed since a few hours.
There is a JsFiddle for :

http://jsfiddle.net/TyrionGraphiste/otx1hx7h/

The red one element is working (he's using the JS code).

And there is the **JS** code :

```
var hoverIntent = function (element, handler, minDuration, callback, duration) {
        
    var timeout = null;
        
    element.on( "mouseover", function () {
        timeout = setTimeout(handler, minDuration);
    } );
        
    element.on( "mouseout", function () {
        var clear = function () {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
       };
            
        setTimeout( function () {
            callback(), clear();
        }, duration );
            
        clear();
    } );
};
    
/* Test */

var element = $( "#element" );
    
hoverIntent(element, function() {

$( element ).animate( {
    height: "80px"}, 200 );
}, 1000, function () {
    $( element ).animate( {height: "50px"}, 200 );
}, 1000 );
```

And here, the **jQuery** code :

```
/* jQuery Event */
    
    $( "body > div.test" ).on( "hoverDuration", function ( e, options ) {
        var
            handler = options.handler,
            minDuration = options.minDuration || 0,
            callback = options.callback,
            duration = options.duration || 0,
            timeout = null,
            clear;
            
            console.log(options);
        
            $( this ).on( {
                mouseover: function () {
                    timeout = setTimeout(handler, minDuration);
                },
                mouseout: function () {
                    clear = function () {
                        clearTimeout( timeout );
                    };
                    
                    setTimeout( function () {
                        callback(), clear();
                    }, duration );
                    
                    clear();
                }
            } );
    } );
    
    $( "body > div.test" ).hoverDuration( {
        handler: function() {
            console.log( $(this) );
            $( this ).animate( {
                height: "80px"
            }, 200 );
        },
        minDuration: 1000,
        callback: function () {
            $( this ).animate( {
                height: "50px"
            }, 200 );
        },
        duration: 1000
    } );
```

In the jQuery code at this line :

```
...
handler: function() {
    console.log( $(this) ); // this one
$( this ).animate( { ...
```

I would like to get the "this" relative to the HTML object targeted, but for moment it's loging the window and not the object.

I tried too like in the documentation here : https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

But no way.. Someone could help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setTimeout` callback is invoked in global object context. You need to provide element context instead. One way is to use `Function.prototype.bind` or in jQuery you can use `$.proxy` function:

```
mouseover: function () {
    timeout = setTimeout($.proxy(handler, this), minDuration);
},
```

If you don't support IE8, then `setTimeout(handler.bind(this), minDuration);`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I go to the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Your response is working. I still have a problem with global context for the callback but I'll see how to fix it.

Comment: You can also save the reference to correct context as `var self = this`, and then use `self` instead of `this` inside callback.

Comment: How do you do this ?

I changed the mouseout : mouseout: function () { clear = function () { clearTimeout( timeout ); }; setTimeout( function () { $.proxy(callback(), _this); clear(); }, duration ); clear(); } 

With _this = this, but not working.

Comment: This line is not correct `$.proxy(callback(), _this);`. Can you see that `callback()` is invoked in wrong context? It should be then `$.proxy(callback, _this)();` but it makes no sense, since you can simply use `call`: `callback.call(_this)`: http://jsfiddle.net/otx1hx7h/6/

Comment: I am going to be honest with you, I don't understand half of the solutions that you proposed.

Great thank you for your help because without you I shall not have arrived there.

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask if you don't understand something. You just need to practice, and everything will start to clear up. Read about `call` method of the function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call